# Node.js CMS options more active & featureful than Calipso?

Tags: node.js, content-management-system

After trolling through quite a number of Node.js CMS hopefuls, it seems that [Calipso](http://calip.so) is the most active / well developed CMS so far.  Am I missing other options or projects that are more robust and mature at this point in time?

Comment: There aren't any mature Node CMSes as far as I know. Besides what's already been suggested here, if you are interested in building your own modules for a CMS you can try that with [hatch](http://hatchjs.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I highly recommend [KeystoneJS](http://www.keystonejs.com), it's still relatively new but i'm already using it in several commercial projects, give it a go! (I also contribute to the project).

Answer (score 4):

Update: Calipso is now dead. We are currently using Apostrophe CMS which in my opinion is more feature-full and better architected for a node.js based cms.

We use Calipso for some of the projects here in my company and it works out fine. If you have love for node you should be fine :)
We constantly review other node based cmses, and so far Calipso is most active and favorite.

Comment: Thanks for the note.  If you discover anything new, would appreciate an update!

Answer (score 1):

[DocPad](http://docpad.org/) seems to be nearly as active as Calipso - [831](https://github.com/bevry/docpad) commits from 22 developers vs [1023](https://github.com/cliftonc/calipso/) commits in Calipso. DocPad has nice docs and lots of plugins.

Comment: Appreciate that info. I'd be curious if any of these now are looking to support [OpalRb](http://opalrb.org) or could easily extend to allow that to be used.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [enduro.js](http://www.endurojs.com/docs/what-is-enduro). It is minimalistic, extensible by node.js and has a pretty nice auto-generated admin interface.